# CSS make my background statrs with color and end with another (similar) color background-image: linear-gradient

Tags: html, css, background, styling

from the top #3a5976 and the bottom #2c4762

sorry if it's hard to read , please copy it to your text editor

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(70,125,149) 19%, 
                          rgb(98,163,179) 60%, 
                          rgb(56,122,122) 80%);
        background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(70,125,149) 19%, 
                          rgb(98,163,179) 60%, 
                          rgb(56,122,122) 80%);
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(70,125,149) 19%, 
                          rgb(98,163,179) 60%, 
                          rgb(56,122,122) 80%);
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(70,125,149) 19%, 
                          rgb(98,163,179) 60%, 
                          rgb(56,122,122) 80%);
        background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(70,125,149) 19%, 
                          rgb(98,163,179) 60%, 
                          rgb(56,122,122) 80%);
           }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
```

Comment: It wouldn't be hard to read if you [formatted it properly](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) (:

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: Like that, much more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substitute your hex values for the rgb() values in your example:

```
body{
background-color: #2c4762; /* fallback for browsers that don't support gradient */
background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, #2c4762, #3a5976 );
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #2c4762, #3a5976 );
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #2c4762, #3a5976 );
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #2c4762, #3a5976 );
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #2c4762, #3a5976 );
}
```

Here's a working fiddle (using #content DIV in place of body): http://jsfiddle.net/daNUM/

Comment: thanx , what if i wanted to make it to a specific amount    4 example the color changes to the bottom of the page , and after scrolling , it stops changing , and till the same color .?

Comment: I don't know that you can, because I've never tried for a gradient, but with images you can set fixed property like `background-attachment:fixed;` see updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/daNUM/1/ (changed top gradient color to white so it's easier to notice)